# App crashed in Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue

Tags: objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I sometimes get the following crash in my app:

```
Crashed Thread:        4  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x7fc2d96277c0 :: NSOperation 0x7fc2d9704440 (QOS: UTILITY)

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000007fc2d968980
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Thread 4 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x7fc2d96277c0 :: NSOperation 0x7fc2d9704440 (QOS: UTILITY)
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff86bd720f objc_release + 31
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff86bdeb81 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 127
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff86bd7383 objc_destructInstance + 116
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff86bd72e5 object_dispose + 22
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff86bdd224 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 242
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9198d2dd -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 205
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff86bdd224 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 242
7   com.my.app                      0x0000000105776471 -[MyNSOperation execute] + 1438
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d59726e -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 1115
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d61b309 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 119
10  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d5f60be __NSFireDelayedPerform + 377
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff919f19f4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff919f1683 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1075
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff919f11da __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 298
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff919e86d1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1841
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff919e7d38 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
16  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d5870f9 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 270
17  com.my.app                      0x000000010574ff10 -[BaseMyNSOperation start] + 711
18  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8d5a41b0 __NSOQSchedule_f + 194
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8d51c453 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8d521083 _dispatch_queue_drain + 754
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8d5276c9 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 549
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8d51fd9b _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 538
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8d51fb48 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff88c884f2 _pthread_wqthread + 1129
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff88c86375 start_wqthread + 13
```

I understood that this has something to do with `Quality of Service`, so I added the following code to the `execute` message of my `NSOperation`:

```
self.qualityOfService = NSQualityOfServiceUtility;
```

I couldn't find any other references to this crash. Anyone can suggest any lead?

Comment: Recently I see often this mysterious crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS in -[__NSArrayM dealloc] in IOS 9.0.2.

Comment: This occurred in OSX 10.11, but both are rather new

Comment: From what I understood so far, the crash is in disposing an `NSMutableArray`, and it probably crashed due to it already being released. Does that make sense?

Comment: May be. But I don't now how you can release already released Array in ARC. May be you cast it somewhere in `CFArray` and use wrong `__bridge` options?

Comment: I don't, so it doesn't make sense indeed. I have another idea though: I've read somewhere that if some class has a weak property of a delegate to my MyNSOperation, it may cause the issue..

Comment: And indeed I have such a weak property with MyNSOperation delegate

Comment: Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901031/segv-accerr-calling-nsnotificationcenter-defaultcenter-removeobserverself-i

Comment: [BaseMyNSOperation start], this is the line of code where you should being your debugging.

Comment: I also have the same crash using DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async in captureOutput(_:didOutput:from), while detecting QR codes using iOS Vision in iOS 12.3.   it crashes in 1 out of 100 scans aprox